# Will a hero take damage from rupture if he was hooked by pudge?

Tags: dota-2, dota

I've seen some matches where a hero under the effect of **rupture** take damages when pushed by **force staff**.

Will it also take damage when the hero is *hooked by pudge*?

Comment: Of course, and any other forced movements like Batrider Flaming Lasso, Rubick Telekinesis, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to their patch notes from [October 13, 2011](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/October_13,_2011_Patch), forced movement should cause damage.

I went through the rest of the patch notes related to Bloodseeker's move rupture and it's the last time it was mentioned in such a way. So yes any forced movement while under the effect will cause damage.

Edit: Here's [the video from the comment](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcXujMdwJo0) below showing someone under the effect of rupture being hooked by Pudge. Thank you Jean-Philippe Roy for the video.

Comment: Indeed! Check out this video :P http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcXujMdwJo0

Answer (score 0):

In the warcraft 3 custom game Dota, yes you did take rupture damage if hooked.
Not sure about Dota 2.